# Unsure of how to Save Stripe Response (product_id) back into my app after product creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Hopefully this will be my last noobish question about Stripe integration

I have a rails 5 Ruby `2.4.0` app and I can create a product through the app and in return it creates a product in my stripe account.

What I'm trying to do, is grab the return from stripe and automatically save the `product_id` stripe generates and save it to the record I created in my app.

this is my product create method in my Product controller:

```
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }

        product = Stripe::Product.create({
          name: @product.prod_name,
          type: @product.prod_type,
          statement_descriptor: @product.statement_descriptor,
          unit_label: @product.unit_label
        })

      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Ive tried to read the stripe docs and am struggling to figure this out in any way shape or form! Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe you read https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby what does `Stripe::Product.create(//your parameters)` return in your rails console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripe's Create Product call has response something like

```
#<Stripe::Product id=prod_CHrutxU4AFaA9S 0x00000a> JSON: {
  "id": "prod_CHrutxU4AFaA9S",
  "object": "product",
  "active": null,
  "attributes": [

  ],
  "caption": null,
  "created": 1518106957,
  "deactivate_on": [

  ],
  "description": null,
  "images": [

  ],
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "name": "monthly",
  "package_dimensions": null,
  "shippable": null,
  "skus": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [

    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/skus?product=prod_CHrutxU4AFaA9S\u0026active=true"
  },
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "type": "service",
  "unit_label": null,
  "updated": 1518106957,
  "url": null
}
```

So the product_id, you are looking for is **id** in response, all you have to do is, to access it with response.id, or in your case product.id like

```
     def create
        @product = Product.new(product_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @product.save
            product = Stripe::Product.create({
              name: @product.prod_name,
              type: @product.prod_type,
              statement_descriptor: @product.statement_descriptor,
              unit_label: @product.unit_label
            })
            @product.product_id = product.id
            @product.save
            format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

Or even better to first see that record is valid & than create stripe product & than save your local product one time like

```
     def create
        @product = Product.new(product_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @product.valid?
            product = Stripe::Product.create({
              name: @product.prod_name,
              type: @product.prod_type,
              statement_descriptor: @product.statement_descriptor,
              unit_label: @product.unit_label
            })
            @product.product_id = product.id
            @product.save
            format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

**MINIMUM POSSIBLE CODE IN CONTROLLER**

As far as I learnt is to follow  **Fat Model, Skinny Controller** rule.

In that case your code will be like

```
      def create
        @product = Product.new(product_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @product.save
            format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

And than product model

```
before_save :create_stripe_product

  def create_stripe_product
     product = Stripe::Product.create({
        name: self.prod_name,
        type: self.prod_type,
        statement_descriptor: self.statement_descriptor,
        unit_label: self.unit_label
       })
     self.product_id = product.id

  end
```